# Why does my second drop down menu not open when it is inside of a another dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am working on a website for my football league, and I want it to be responsive on both mobile and laptop.

When I reduce my screen size, to something similar to of a phone. My navbar becomes a menu with a hamburger icon, which when opens displays all the menu options.

However, inside those menu options is another drop down menu with a list of all the teams in the tournament. When I'm in the menu hamburger menu, the second dropdown with the teams does not open.

Here is a few screenshots:

[image: Screenshot of when the menu is in a laptop screen resolution]

**Screenshot of when the menu is in a laptop screen resolution**

#### when I view the menu using a phone screen resolution

[image: On phone]

When I click on the drop down menu, it just close all of it completely.

## My code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/team_logos/LOGO FINAL PNG.png" alt="JBPL logo"/></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            Menu
            <i class="fas fa-bars ms-1"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="team.html">Teams</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Something</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">Else</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#team">X</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Teams
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Mercury Wingers</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Curry Blasters</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Spice FC</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Curry Blasters</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Bomb Squad</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Error 404</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Invincible Knights</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Space Monkey Mafia</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Skull Crushers</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Thunder Warriros</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item nav-link" href="#">Fear Control</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What's the Bootstrap version you used?

Comment: I added the necessary Bootstrap cdn and also added the `bg-dark` class to the `nav` tag and seems like it is working fine and not reproducing the issue you were having.